# Regular Expression for finding a parentheses in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all matches for a capital letter followed by a parentheses i.e. A), B), C) etc. I tested it out with re-try (http://re-try.appspot.com/) and it works perfectly, but when I implement it in my program it gives me an error message:  sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis

```
parens = re.findall(r'[A-Z]\)', test_file)
```

It seems that it is ignoring the escape character, but why is that? 
Any help or alternative approaches would be much appreciated.

Comment: No repro for me. I can do it normally.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: It throws exception if I do that. Not sure about OP

Comment: That is working for me. You will only get that error when you remove that escape from the `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> st='first A) you have B) and then C)'
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z]\)',st)
['A)', 'B)', 'C)']
```

or:

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Z]\\)',st)
['A)', 'B)', 'C)']
```

Is `test_file` a string actually? What you have should work (try it in the Python shell) and so my suspicion is your second parameter to `re.findall`...

If, as your naming would suggest, it is a file object, you would need to do this:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_matches=re.findall(pattern,line)
        ... do something with a list of matches from that line
        ... next line
```

or, for the whole file

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents=f.read()
    file_matches=re.findall(pattern,contents,flags=re.MULTILINE)
    ... do something with a list of matches from the whole file
```

or, the encoding of that file may be wrong...

Comment: Yes, that was it. I wasn't reading the file in correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression is fine, the problem might be the encoding of test_file.

Check this [Python Unicode Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168894/python-unicode-regular-expression) to see if anything helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That will come in handy for sure. In this case it ended up being my mistake with the way I was reading the file.